# Json unexpected end of string buggy character

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, web-scraping

Just scraped some json from a webpage and now when I try to parse it using vscode I get an 'unexpected end of string' error on the "content" line:
Here's the json

```
    {
    "name": "Anna Vergnas",
    "date": "04/18/2018 4:30pm",
    "content": "L'appartement se situe au métro porte de Montreuil.Nous sommes au rez de chaussée d 'une belle et grande cour pavée, qui accueille volontier une baignade de soleil, des apéros au milieu des jardinières et . Cadre plutôt exceptionnel pour Paris, puisque vous avez un jardin et une terrasse dont vous profitez as you want (dans le respect de chacun).Pour plus d'
    info contactez moi en mp: )",
"number" : "null"}
```

Here's part of the code using for scraping ( blocks is the div of the container):

```
let result = []

                let name = blocks[z].querySelector('.fwn.fcg') ? blocks[z].querySelector('.fwn.fcg').innerText : null
            let fb_url = blocks[z].querySelector('h5 a') ? blocks[z].querySelector('h5 a').href : null
            let date = blocks[z].querySelector('abbr') ? blocks[z].querySelector('abbr').title : null
            let content = blocks[z].querySelector('._5pbx.userContent._3576') ? blocks[z].querySelector('._5pbx.userContent._3576').innerText : null
            let number = blocks[z].querySelector('._5pbx.userContent._3576') ? blocks[z].querySelector('._5pbx.userContent._3576').innerText.replace(/\s/g, '').match(/((\+)33|0)[1-9](\d{2}){4}/g) : null
            result.push({ name, fb_url, date, content, number, group_url})
```

Comment: Can you also share the code where you tried to parse it ? And the error you get

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi i've uploaded a pic in the post for you :)

Comment: Please share the error here using code tags, not via an image. Also, post the code that is used for scraping.

Comment: @mission712 OP likely "scraped" it by typing what we see in the image, and OP mistyped it.

Comment: Your last line says `number "null"}` but in the image it is `number ": null,"` with more to come.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Here ya go, updated the post

Comment: This doesn't give us any info about the original page, and what you expect when you scrape the page. Please supply those as well so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what is shown in your post the `content` contains an unencoded new line, which is not allowed in JSON.